# Modifying Android TextView to line-break only at specified character

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

I'd like to modify the android `TextView` to line-break only at a specified character. For instance, let's say the specified character is `+` and the string is as below:

> + Apple  + Banana + Coconut + Dragon fruit

**The default `TextView` behaviour** when text overflows.

> + Apple  + Banana + Coconut + Dragon
> fruit *(New line)*

**Desired behaviour**

> + Apple  + Banana + Coconut 
> + Dragon fruit *(New line)*

I always struggle with custom views. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an unicode character named `NO-BREAK SPACE`: `\u00A0`.

Example: 
`+\u00A0Apple +\u00A0Banana +\u00A0Coconut +\u00A0Dragon\u00A0fruit`

This will appear as `+ Dragon fruit` on UI, but this piece won't be broken in two lines.

Comment: This is also useful for formatting currencies:

US\u00A0$\u00A0130.00 or R\u00A0$\u00A0500,00.

Comment: This saved a me (and the phones that will be running the app) a lot of time!

Answer (score -1):

the approach here would be simple just make a method which would be called when the user enters and text in the edittext and then use a simple if block where if the entered character is the same as the one you have decided then just add \n to the text entered. It is the command for new line in java
No need of any custom view.
Remember always keep things simple while coding